# how to fix a spreadsheet language?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, language, localization

I am building a spreadsheet and I would like to ensure that all the content is in English, even when the spreadsheet is shared with users having another language set in Office. An example when it is not (French is the default language):

[image]

Is this possible, on a document level? I know that I can [manage languages on **my** Office installation](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Switch-between-different-languages-by-setting-the-proofing-language-667ba67a-a202-42fd-8596-edc1fa320e00), I would like to understand if I can override this setting on others' installations (for that document)

Comment: I know you can format individual cells to show dates in a certain language ([Reference](http://excelribbon.tips.net/T011782_Specifying_a_Language_for_the_TEXT_Function.html)) but I don't yet know of a workbook-level setting.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, I do not know how I could have missed the setting! Can you please rewrite your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @EngineerToast Do you know if this overrides system settings or just office settings?

Comment: @Raystafarian Hard-coding the language into a particular cell overrides all other settings for language, both Office and System.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a VBA workaround that will set the format for all dates to be a particular language. It is written to just format dates but you can change that. Based on the options in the "Format Cells" dialog, I believe it only has an effect for dates, times, and special formats but you can technically add the LCID to any format. You're going to need the [list of language IDs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664.aspx) to set `LCID` to whatever value you need. (Be sure to use LCID Hex, not LCID Dec)

```
Sub SetLanguageFormat()

    'Declarations
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim f As String
    Const LCID As String = "[$-0409]"
    Dim reg 'As RegExp  'Removed for late binding

    'Setup regular expression
    Set reg = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    reg.Global = True
    reg.IgnoreCase = True
    reg.Pattern = "\[\$\-+[\w]*[\w]\]"

    'Loop through all cells and change the date formate
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
        If IsDate(cell.Value) Then
            f = cell.NumberFormat
            If reg.Execute(f).Count > 0 Then
                'Language is set so replace it
                f = reg.Replace(f, LCID)
            Else
                'Langauge is not set so add it
                f = LCID & f
            End If
            cell.NumberFormat = f
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

---

You can also do this one-by-one through the [manual method](http://excelribbon.tips.net/T011782_Specifying_a_Language_for_the_TEXT_Function.html) by right-clicking on a cell and then clicking "Format Cells..."

Comment: Interesting, +1!